# How to implement a user flow with email verification after completing the registration form?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

The default user flows in Azure AD B2C require the user to first confirm his mail address before completing the registration form:
[image]

That's not the standard registration behaviour we normally see on today's registrations. How can I configure (or build a new one) the signup process so the user first completes the form and then at the end gets an email with a confirmation link?

Answer (score 1):

Regrettably, this is not possible with User flows at this time.

Azure AD B2C has two ways of defining User Journeys: User flows and Custom policies. User flows are the predefined authentication flows you have been using: they can be set up in the portal and customized a little. Custom policies are fully customizable with declarative XML programming.

If you want to deviate from what Microsoft has defined for User flows, you must switch to Custom policies.

Here is a comparison between the two: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-overview